# Ckeditor não mostra tags php em textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o Ckeditor, tudo corre bem, porém, não consigo fazer postagens ('tutoriais') que contenham tags php. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
acho 'teste';
```

A tag `<?php` não é exibida. Existe alguma configuração do próprio Ckeditor que resolveria isso?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução aqui: http://komlenic.com/246/encoding-entities-to-work-with-ckeditor-3/

Com isso, antes de mandar o conteúdo para o Ckeditor eu estou fazendo uma substituição de caracteres:

```
str_replace('&', '&amp;', $post->conteudo);
```